# Adding /*const*/ instead of const qualifier to char * param in function prototype

Tags: c, function, constants, const-correctness

I am facing a function which takes a pointer to a `char` array but it performs only read operations on the mem the `char *` points to.

I could add `const` to the prototype directly before the `char *` parameter, but this would break the rest of the non const-correct code. I decided to add a comment `/*const*/` instead to indicate that the function performs only read operations.

However, this confuses my colleagues and I wonder if adding the comments is a common approach and the criticism is unjustified.

Example:

```
int func(const char *readat);
```

versus

```
int func(/*const*/ char *readat);
```

Comment: Fix the non-const correct code?

Comment: If `func(const char *readat)` instead of `func(char *readat)` breaks existing code, then there shouldn't be `const`.

Comment: In which way does it break the rest of the "non const-correct code"? If you want to perform read-only operations on your char array the approach of using const is perfectly fine. If anywhere else inside your function this char array is manipulated however, you may consider placing this code anywhere else since this just doesn't make sense from a design perspective.

Comment: Where is the non-const code ?

Comment: Adding `const` to your function prototype is proper use to indicate that the parameter is read-only.  Although it won't break (i.e. cause errors in) existing code, the compiler will probably generate warnings.  Casting the passed variable where the function is called as the constant data type will correct that.  You can also just mention that the parameter is "read only" in your function's comment block.

Comment: It is not an error to pass a non-const argument to something that takes a `const` argument, i.e., the callers of `func` won't break by the addition of `const`. If `func` itself calls something that takes a non-const argument, and you know that the other function doesn't actually modify its argument, either add `const` to it (if you can), or cast the argument to `const` inside `func` (if you can't modify it). (If it _does_ modify the argument, then the `const` is obviously incorrect and you shouldn't add it or any comment suggesting otherwise.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `const` to the function parameter won't break any calling code.  It is allowed to assign a non-const object to a const object.

So this is allowed:

```
char c;
char *p = &c;
const char *cp = p;
```

But this is not:

```
char c;
const char *cp = &c;
char *p = cp;
```